# Safely remove USB drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to safely remove a USB drive programatically from a powershell aplication. My current code works for single-volume usb drives. Code follows:

```
$Eject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$Eject.NameSpace(17).ParseName($usbDrvLetter+“:”).InvokeVerb(“Eject”)
```

As I said, this works for single-volume drives. But I have a two-volume USB drive that cannot be removed like that. How can I access the drive itself and `invokeVerb("Eject")` it, including all of its volumes?

Comment: If your drives are J: and K:, what happens when you run your code on J:? Does it fail? Is there error output you can paste into the question?

Comment: I get no error. The volume stays connected and accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an USB drive which shows up 2 Volumes, it should also have 2 different Volume letters. Try to eject both and it should be alright.